# C# why LINQ string array Contains show false

Tags: c#

my question is ABC006 is in testA, why Contains show false?
and testB  show true?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] testA = " ABC666,777".Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine(testA.Contains("ABC666"));
    string testB =" ABC666";
    Console.WriteLine( testB.Contains("ABC666"));
        
        

    
    }
}
```

Comment: `" ABC666" != "ABC666"` - whitespaces matter.

Comment: As @FranzGleichmann, Whitespaces matter. You can remove white-spaces before Splitting the string using [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0).  i.e `string[] testA = " ABC666,777".Trim().Split(',');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your difference in the two `Contains` methods:

[image: contains]

The first contains is asking "does the enumerable contain this value". The second is asking "does this string contain this other string".

The first one does not ask "does any string in this enumerable contain the other string".

To do that you would need this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(testA.Any(x => x.Contains("ABC666")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `testA` will contain the strings `" ABC666"` and `"777"`, and not the string `"ABC666"` (note the extra space at the beginning of the first one).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Split function to the split the original string to an array.
The `testA` contains 2 elements after the split:

1. " ABC666"
2. "777"

If you call the Contains function on the array, it will check if any of the elements contains the **exact match** of the string given. Thanks the reason you are getting False.

You can use the [Linq Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) function to get the functionality you want:

```
Console.WriteLine(testA.Any( a=> a.Contains("ABC666")));
```

This will call for [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0) function of every string in the array.

Comment: and here is the same answer